# Javascript generator function?

Tags: javascript, syntax, generator

Am I stupid of what does this generator function in Javascript do:

```
function* generator() {
  let hook, waiting = yield new Promise(resolve => {
    function* wait() { resolve(yield) }
    hook = wait();
    hook.next();
  });
  hook.next(waiting);
}
```

Source: https://github.com/padlet/async-semaphore

Comment: Did I phrase my question wrong?

Comment: There is a comment in the github repo explaining the code ([index.js](https://github.com/padlet/async-semaphore/blob/c98d8678d3fdad38b96b10127b18db420ae38e46/index.js) at line 102)

Comment: doesn't explain the syntax of how this dude is assigning two variables from one initialization

Comment: @NickParsons I get http error 406

Comment: @Asleepace 
`hook` starts off as undefined, and only gets assigned within the Promise constructor

Comment: You misread the assignment. It is just short for `let hook; let waiting = `

Comment: @trincot good looks, I'd accept that as an answer, thanks!

Comment: @qrsngky I'm not sure why the link doesn't work, but if you go to the link Asleepace shared and then open the index.js and navigate to line 102 there are some comments that explain the code.

Comment: @NickParsons Maybe it has to do with the referrer. So, no direct link (hotlinking) but it can be reached if you use https://github.com/padlet/async-semaphore . Same error if I try https://github.com/padlet/async-semaphore/blob/master/index.js directly, or if I go through the link and refresh the browser tab.

Comment: @qrsngky it's just I learned about this super cool company in San Francisco and I want to be prepared for my coding interview, I have the link (aka the snippet), where can I practice using things like this in real life?

Comment: @qrsngky hm yeah, maybe something to do with the referrer header. Strange though, I haven't seen that happen before. Considering github allows you to copy a permalink for a line number, I would expect it to work (unless maybe you can disable this behavior at a repo-level somehow)

Comment: @NickParsons stack overflow is probably rendering assets out of order, prob could benefit from something like this ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one took a couple minutes to process.

The `resolve(yield)` part actually gives the promise the value of the 2nd next() call's params (waiting). I think this could be made in a cleaner way with just 1 generator.

[generator.next() on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Generator/next)

The result is:

```js
let g = generator()
g.next().value.then(console.log) // returns a pending promise
g.next("test")                   // returns nothing important but
// the then callback logs "test"
```

So you can put as many callbacks on the first call of generator.next().value, and you let them all go on the second, while also passing in a param to the first which you can chain in the regular promise fashion.

Comment: Ah shit I was scratching my head for a second (still am), but this makes it more clear thanks!